# How to write my scenario outline when i want to use multiple scenarios

Tags: cucumber, gherkin, feature-file

Can i join multiple Scenario outlines with multiple examples

```
Something Like this:

Scenario Outline: Valid Scenario
Given i have written <test>
When i execute <code>
Then i <expect> 

Given the test <result>
Then validate the <response>
Then i then validate <query>

*Examples: 
|test| | code | |expect |
|1   | |SOPLN | |"input"|

Examples: 
|result| | response| |query| 
|pass  | |200      | |select* from table1|*
```

And can i use double pipes instead of single pipes
    |test| | code | |expect | instead of      |test| code |expect |

Comment: U can have multiple examples table with a single scenariooutline what is the use of the double pipes?

Comment: "Is there any difference between double and single pipes?, In this scenario can we use double pipes if the syntax is not invalid?"

Comment: Dont think double works. Try double pipes if it works good.

Comment: It works but was just curious if that is used for any other purpose in Gherkin.